# React state variable value appearing to be null

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to access a value of my state variable, but it appears to be null when I change the date, but If I change any other input field, I don't get it null
Here is the [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-6wbchf?file=src%2FApp.js) to stackblitz running app.

If you open the console and type something in any field you can check the value of `filter` variable to be same as what you type, but if you click on the date range input, it will show you null, I'm scratching my head for hours around this.
Thanks in advance to helping hands

Comment: This looks like a bug in react-bootstrap-daterangepicker, which isn't updating the component with the newest onEvent callback. It's using the callback that's closed over your initial state only. A terrible hack is to force the daterange component to fully unmount and remount, with `<DateRangePicker onEvent={onDateChange} key={filter}>`

Comment: Do I need to force mount in my `onDateChange` function or `useEffect` when my filter value changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`react-bootstrap-daterangepicker` looks like abandonware, I'd pick a different library.

If you want to keep using it, note that the `onEvent` callback isn't updated when your component re-renders. So to get the latest state, use the setState callback:

```
    const onDateChange = (event, picker) => {
        ...
        setFilter(filter => {
            console.log('new filter', filter);
            return {...filter, hi: 'bye'};
        });
    }
```

This will let you access the latest `filter` state of your component even though the callback has closed over the stale initial render state.

The very first time your component renders, it runs the entire body of the function component. So it creates the function `onDateChange` on the first render. This function has access to the `filter` variable through a Javascript **closure**. You should familiarize yourself with closures if you aren't already. One way to think about it is your `onDateChange` has access to the parent variable scope where `filter` lives, even after the component has finished rendering. `onDateChange` has "closed over" the outer scope and can access the `filter` variable through the closure.

Every time your functional component "renders", like when you change state, the entire body of the component's function re-runs. In this case, it creates an entirely new `onDateChange` function, which will close over the **latest** version of the `filter` variable from state. So in theory, the new `onDateChange` function reference, when called by the internal guts of the Datepicker library, *should* have access to the latest `filter` state.

Apparently, what's happening instead, is the Datepicker library is only using the `onDateChange`  from the **first** render, and not updating it when you pass in the newer created `onDateChange`. One reason a library might choose to do this is to avoid removing and re-attaching event listeners every time a render occurs, which could be important if there are lots of child elements that need to re-render. That's probably not what's happening with this Datepicker library, it's probably just a poorly designed and outdated library.

So your Datepicker renders once with the initial `onDateChange` function that's closed over your initial `filter` state. Every time your component renders, a new `onDateChange` closed over a new `filter` variable is created, but the Datepicker doesn't use the latest one, it uses the stale initial `onDateChange` one. The closure over the `filter` state isn't updated when your component re-renders, instead and entirely new `onDateChange` is made each render. The initial `onDateChange` is still around in memory and has access to the initial `filter` variable in memory.

If you were to call `setFilter({...filter, new: 'value' })` inside the callback, every time it runs, that `filter` variable would be the stale initial value from your initial component render. The `filter` variable never gets updated inside the stale `onDateChange` function. It would keep overwriting your filter with `null`.

For problems like this, React provides a **callback** to the `setState` function that **will always have access the latest state**. So instead of

```
setFilter({ ...filter, newData })
```

you can do

```
setFilter(latestFilterState => { return {...latestFilterState, newData  } })
```

and React will call that inner callback function, setting `latestFilterState` to the latest value of the state. This works even though `setFilter` is also "stale" from the first render.

Comment: Amazing, it worked like charm, but I don't understand, it will be quite helpful for me, if you slightly explain how does it work

Comment: I gave an explanation a try

Comment: Thank you so much @Andy, your way of explaining is exceptional.