# Why does my state update correctly only when used with a callback?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a chat front end using React.

Whenever I receive a new message I handle it like that:

```
socketRef.current.on("chat_message", (data: Message) => {
  if (data.senderId === friendId) {
  setMessages(messages => [...messages, data]);
  }
});
```

and it works, the new message is appended to the previous messages and displayed alongside them.
But when I do not use the callback in the setMessages, like that:

```
socketRef.current.on("chat_message", (data: Message) => {
  if (data.senderId === friendId) {
  setMessages([...messages, data]);
  }
});
```

the messages state is updated to only contain the latest message, contained in the data object, i.e. whenever I receive a new message, I see only it, the previous messages are erased. Why does it work like that? I have always been updating the React state without that callback pattern and it always worked, but now it does not.

Here's the whole socket.io setup on the front end for reference:

```
useEffect(() => {
      if (isFocused) {
        socketRef.current = io(apiHost + "/chat", {
          query: {
            userId: authState.id,
            friendId: friendId,
          },
          transports: ["websocket"],

        })

        socketRef.current.on("connect", () => {
          console.log("Connected to server");
        });
  
        socketRef.current.on("recent_messages", (data: any) => {
          setMessages(data["recentMessages"]);
          setRoom(data["room"]);
          setLoading(false);
        });
  
        socketRef.current.on("chat_message", (data: Message) => {
            if (data.senderId === friendId) {
              setMessages(messages => [...messages, data]);
            }
        });
  
        return () => {
          socketRef.current.disconnect();
          console.log("Disconnected from server");
        };
      } else {
        socketRef.current.disconnect();
        console.log("Disconnected from server");
      }
  }, [isFocused]);
```

Comment: Stale closure. You would have to add `message` to the dependency array to fix it

Comment: OK, so just to be sure I understand it - when the useEffect is being declared when the component is being mounted, it takes a snapshot of messages object which is empty at the moment of its initialization and thereafter it always uses that empty snapshot whenever the useEffect is being triggered, right?

Comment: As @konrad says, the `messages` state is captured at the time the  event handler is created, so it never knows about the updates. In the latter form React passes the _current state value_ in as an argument, so you get the interim updates. If you added messages as a dependency the event handler would get updated every time messages changes, but you’d have to unregister the old one every time, so your second example is the better way in my opinion.

Comment: This is a pretty common question on Stackoverflow. Here's an exact duplicate, where I tried to write out an answer about how closures interact with functions like these. https://stackoverflow.com/a/73255106/743464