# React useEffect, loading data and changing that data

Tags: reactjs

I have a simple component that I am trying to load posts in useEffect. The posts load fine, but when I then try to change the array in the setTimeout, and try to access the posts array, it is empty and therefore gives me an error when trying to change the title.

What am I doing wrong here? I assume that it is rerendering somewhere and setting the state back to the initial [], how can I fix this code so that it successfully changes the item in the array?

````
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function Posts() {

    const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
    console.log(posts.length);
    useEffect(() => {

        fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((json) => { setPosts(json); });

    }, []);

    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(posts.length);
        var allPosts = [...posts];
        allPosts[10].title = "a new title";
        setPosts(allPosts);

    }, 6000);

    return (
        <div>
            {posts.map((post) => <div key={post.id}>{post.id}: <input type='text' readOnly value={post.title} /></div>)}
        </div>);
}```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest thing to do here is to call the `setTimeout` after your `fetch()` finishes, along with the `useState` callback, to make sure you're grabbing the latest state when your timeout executes.

```
useEffect(() => {

    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((json) => {
            setPosts(json);

            setTimeout(() => {
                setPosts((posts) => {
                    console.log(posts.length);
                    var allPosts = [...posts];
                    allPosts[10].title = "a new title";
                    return allPosts;
                })
            }, 6000);
        });

}, []);
```

You're confused about how React renders and state work. This exact type of question is asked a few dozen times a day on Stackoverflow, so I wrote a [longer answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73255106/743464) describing the interaction of closures and rendering and React.

In your code, your component renders once with empty posts, and you kick off a `setTimeout`, which "closes over" the initial value of `posts`. Your `setTimeout` callback takes a snapshot of the current variables in the parent scope, and that's all it has access to.

When your `fetch` finishes, it calls `setState` and triggers a new render, which is an entirely new run of your component's function. Your `setTimeout` function is still hanging out in memory with its previous snapshot of the state. The *new* `setTimeout` will get access to the newer variables from the render, but your older one will fire first, and barf, because it only has access to the initial render's data.

Also note that in this solution, there's still a bug, because if your component unmounts before the 6 seconds is up, the `setTimeout` callback will fire and try to set state on a unmounted component, which will cause an error. It's up to you to track the timeout ID in a ref, and clear it on unmount.